# UIButton with rounded corners and border

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, rounded-corners

I want to set border on UIButton and rounded corners ONLY in one side

I use this code:

```
//set rounded corners on top
UIBezierPath *maskPath =  [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.scanButton.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.scanButton.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

self.scanButton.layer.mask = maskLayer;

// set border
self.scanButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.scanButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
[self.scanButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

[image]

How can I make proper border in top corners?

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 2.0 version

The corners of your border are clipping because you've probably set the background color of your view on the UIView itself. A better way to do this would just be to set the fill color directly on your layer. This could be done like this:

```
let button = ... // your existing UIButton
let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
borderLayer.borderWidth = 2.0

let borderPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds,
    byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight],
    cornerRadii: CGSize(width:10.0, height: 10.0))
    borderLayer.path = borderPath.CGPath

button.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

The above would give you this result without clipped corners:

[image: example button]

I've put together a UIButton subclass using this method where the border radius can be set on each corner of the button individually, check it out here: https://gist.github.com/alexpls/95279b3f9a2da7f2d7bf, hopefully it helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I've changed the answer so it includes a code example more targeted at the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

you're probably better off subclassing UIButton and overriding drawRect: with your custom drawing. you need to implement a CGContext and add your UIBezierPath then stroke it. Can't recall if you need to make it a CGPath first, but i don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following answer - [Stroke masked CALayer in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357132/stroke-masked-calayer-in-ios) He using combination of mask & shape layer to draw such custom border. You will need to turn off a regular border for masked layer.